# Angular Side Bar with “Half” side mode

Tags: angular, angular-material, sidebar, sidenav

I want to set up a left sidenav which will open and close dynamically, exactly like this [Angular Material Side Bar with "Half" side mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46835554/angular-material-side-bar-with-half-side-mode) but in angular js..Is there any suggestion?