# Angular: Toggle Sidenav with Icons across 3 components

Tags: angular, typescript, sidenav

I am trying to develop a homepage which toggles a sidenav which I have done successfully however, if the sidenav is closed I still want to show the icons on the lefthand side rather than icons and text (when opened).
I have three components: app, header and side-nav.

The toggler is in the header component and I have created an event binder so that the Text in the sideNav disappears when toggled. This issue is that the page does not adjust as a consquence and the sidenav is still the same size but with less text.
Please see code below (i've only taken snippet of code that i think are relevent to this problem).

Not sure if this is an typescript issue or something css?

**header.html**

```
  <button mat-icon-button (click)="toggleSideNav()"><mat-icon>menu</mat-icon></button>
```

**header.ts**

```
 @Output() onToggleSideNav: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

toggleSideNav() {
    this.onToggleSideNav.emit();
  }
```

**app.html**

```
<mat-drawer-container>
    <mat-drawer mode="side" [opened]=true>
        <app-side-nav [isExpanded]='sideNavOpen'></app-side-nav>
    </mat-drawer>
    <mat-drawer-content>
        <app-header (onToggleSideNav)='sideNavToggler()'></app-header>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </mat-drawer-content>
</mat-drawer-container>
```

**app.ts**

```
sideNavOpen: boolean = true;
  sideNavToggler() {
    this.sideNavOpen = !this.sideNavOpen
  }
```

**sidenav.html**

```
<mat-nav-list>
    <a mat-list-item routerLink="/home" routerLinkActive="list-item-active">
        <mat-icon>home</mat-icon>
        <h4 mat-line *ngIf="isExpanded">Home</h4>
    </a>
</mat-nav-list>
```

**sidenav.ts**

```
 @Input() isExpanded: boolean = true;
```

[image]

Comment: Your question is pretty similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46835554/angular-material-side-bar-with-half-side-mode

Answer (score 0):

As I got from your code...

1. The sidenav.ts file has *hardcoded* Input. So no matter what value it has it will be overwritten with the `true` value. Leave it unset to get its incoming dynamic value during initialization `@Input() isExpanded: boolean;`.*If* you need to handle an inputted value, then it could be done in `ngOnChanges()`.
2. Original `<mat-drawer>` has no hardcoded width and can react to its inner content size change (https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview#sidenav-autosize).
   Probably, your `app-side-nav` component's template has not changed width. Per your request, it should change according to the `isExpanded`'s value. Please, check that `isExpanded` is used for it. For example,

```html
<div id="app-side-nav" [ngClass]="{'expandedWidth': isExpanded, 
  'autoWidth': !isExpanded}">
...
</div>
```

Where CSS is following.

```css
.expandedWidth {
  width: 200px;
}
.autoWidth{
  width: auto;
}
```

3. Also, there is a point to add some pleasant CSS things to make your app more smooth. Add `transitions` to the width change. Then your app will be smoother in changes. For example, add a transition for any change in 1 second with 'ease-out' timing function to the `<app-side-nav>`'s parent element: `transition: all 1s ease-out;`.

Hope, this will help.