# Angular Material mat-sidenav-content not showing

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Angular Material Version: @angular/material@14.0.2

I am building a web application using the Angular framework for the first time.
The app-routing-module lazy loads a dashboard module that declares the desired components and imports the required modules. The dashboard module imports a dashboard routing module which holds the routes with the WrapperComponent as the parent and the side nav content as the children, split up into different components.

dashboard-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AboutComponent } from './components/about/about.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './components/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { WrapperComponent } from './components/wrapper/wrapper.component';

const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: '',
    component: WrapperComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: 'dashboard', // --> localhost:4200/dashboard
            component: DashboardComponent,
        },
        {
            path: 'login', // --> localhost:4200/login
            component: LoginComponent,
        },
        {
            path: 'about', // --> localhost:4200/about
            component: AboutComponent,
        }
    ]
},
{
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '/dashboard',
    pathMatch: 'full'
}
];

@NgModule({
     imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
     exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class DashboardRoutingModule { }
```

wrapper.component.html

```
<mat-sidenav-container>
<mat-sidenav #sideNav mode="side" opened="opened">
    <app-side-nav>
    </app-side-nav>
</mat-sidenav>
<mat-sidenav-content>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

The app-side-nav component consists of the router links.

```
<div class="sidenav">
<div class="logo">
    <a (click)="toggleMenuState()" class="simple-text logo-mini">
        <div class="logo-img">
            <img src="./assets/images/sample_logo.png" alt="logo">
        </div>
    </a>
</div>

<ul class="nav">
    <li class="active nav-list-item"><a routerLink="/default-route"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-nav-icon"><span class="nav-item-text">Dashboard</span></i></a></li>
    <li class="nav-list-item"><a routerLink="/some-route"><i class="fa fa-group fa-nav-icon"><span class="nav-item-text">Groups</span></i></a></li>
    <li class="nav-list-item"><a routerLink="/some-route"><i class="fa fa-line-chart fa-nav-icon"><span class="nav-item-text">Charts</span></i></a></li>
    <li class="nav-list-item"><a routerLink="/some-route"><i class="fa fa-book fa-nav-icon"><span class="nav-item-text">Portfolio</span></i></a></li>
    <li class="nav-list-item"><a routerLink="/login"><i class="fa fa-user fa-nav-icon"><span class="nav-item-text">Login</span></i></a></li>
    <li class="nav-list-item"><a routerLink="/some-route"><i class="fa fa-gear fa-nav-icon"><span class="nav-item-text">Settings</span></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

This seems to work fine because I can see the relevant content being loaded in the DOM depending on the button clicked. But for some reason, the content is not visible.
Here is a screenshot of the dashboard component loaded. For some reason, it is loading with a margin of 1920px but even when removed the content is still not visible.
[image: Application DOM]

The structure seems to work yet there is something not quite right otherwise the content would show. Would appreciate any thoughts, suggestions or further questions.

Comment: Try posting the complete project (simplified html) on stackblitz and share us the link. Its important to know how the dashboard component and app-routing.module.ts are connected.

Comment: Why is `router-outlet` inside the sidenav content?

Comment: To answer Sergey's question; To show the routes set in dashboard-routing.module.ts which are the pages of the application. With regards to Swapnil's comment. I tried adding my project to stackblitz but I couldn't get it to run. But at least you have the code and can have a look at the structure yourself. Here is the link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-86p858.  I appreciate both of your comments.

Comment: @AdrianMangion this link is not working, it doesn't have src/app

Comment: I assume that router-outlet is the content of the page. Not sidenav. Sidenav content is the content of the sidenav. Meanwhile you have placed it there. So no wonder there is a blank page

Comment: Here is the link to the repo: https://github.com/adrianmangion/growthon

Comment: Sergey, I disagree. As seen in their documentation, it is common practise to put the content of the page inside the 'mat-sidenav-content'. It is the 'mat-sidenav' that contains the contents of the sidenav.

Answer (score 0):

I think your proble is material think that your app-side-nav or mat-sidenav have a full screen width, on the screenshot as I can see, content have a 1920px margin-left, this means that your view out of the bound of screen.
[image: your screenshot]
There is my example with correct margin, pay attention to your nav component:
[image: my screenshot]
[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fobgc7)
Hope this helps.

Comment: I already tried adjusting that margin but the content is still not showing.

Comment: @AdrianMangion after investigation a source code of mat-sidenav, I confidient that 1920px margin sets for content because angular thinks that your sidenav so wide, could you debug width of your sidenav component? In my example everything works perfect

Answer (score 0):

After checking the rendered template it seems that your code lacks the routing precision.

Your `app-routing.module.ts` says that for path `""` it should use `DashboardModule`. In the module you say that for path `""` it should render a `WrapperComponent`. And after this point it has no default route.

So, basically what happens is that your wrapper component is rendered, however none of its children matches the route. To fix it, you have two options:

- provide handler for "" route in the wrappers children routes
- add a redirect to one of the routes using a wildcard route as I did in the Stackblitz fork of your GitHub project.

[Stackblitz fork](https://%20https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-jr2els?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fdashboard%2Fcomponents%2Fwrapper%2Fwrapper.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fdashboard%2Fdashboard.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fdashboard%2Fdashboard-routing.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp-routing.module.ts)

That is to fix that router outlet does not render anything.

Another problem is `<mat-sidenav #sideNav mode="side" opened="opened">`, as you are assigning a string to the boolean flag, which means that it will be always truthy and won't display what's underneath.

In result removing `opened="opened"` and adding a redirection to the dashboard page we can see the "dashboard works!"

[image]

P.S. Looking at the examples in the docs it doesn't look to be designed to work the way you want it to. Rather show or hide behavior. Not expand.

P.S.S. You could try using [autoresize and toggle width manually](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview#resizing-an-open-sidenav) for the ever open sidenav as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46835554/angular-material-side-bar-with-half-side-mode)